Obtain the x1,y1 x2,y2 coords not only x1,y1 from draggable line in reactive plotly
related to: # Movable lines in Plotly R
I am trying to create an interactive figure with draggable line in x,y space.
If I use the same example from the referenced question:
library(plotly)
plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter') %>%
    layout(shapes = list(
                    #vertical line
                    list(type = "line", x0 = 0.4, x1 = 0.4, 
                            y0 = 0, y1 = 1, yref = "paper"),
                    #horizontal line
                    list(type = "line", x0 = 0, x1 = 1, 
                            y0 = 30, y1 = 30, xref = "paper"))) %>%
    # allow to edit plot by dragging lines
    config(edits = list(shapePosition = TRUE))

Now if called from a reactive shiny. I can retrieve the edits with:
newData <- plotly::event_data("plotly_relayout")
print(newData0)

$`shapes[0].x1`
[1] 80.65517

$`shapes[0].y1`
[1] 2.232316

However, I move the line in x,y direction. Not only horizontally and vertically. So, I expect x1,y1 and x2,y2 coordinates.

Is there a way to get the complete line position (the 2 points creating it)?

See if this q & a doesn't get where you need to go. Otherwise, make your question reproducible...not the graph so much as how you're applying it in Shiny.

The only way to do that is to create a reactiveVal for each x and y, and update them on drag

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
